# How to make .bak file for SQL Server 2008 Express

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-express

How to create a `.bak` file for selected database table in SQL Server 2008?

I have a `TESTDB` database which have more than 15 tables. I want to make `.bak` file only for 5 selected tables.

So how can I create that?

Comment: You can't do that - SQL Server backups are **database-level** backups.

Comment: @marc_s are you sure ?
after the follow of Praveen steps 2 files (LDF and MDF) are generated.

Comment: SQL Server has at least one data file (`.mdf` - could be multiple) and one transaction log file (`.ldf`) - but that's **not** a backup and that can't be limited to a group of tables - it's everything or nothing

Comment: In theory you could move your 5 tables to a different filegroup, take a filegroup-level backup, and do a partial restore of the primary + that filegroup. But it would require Enterprise Edition on the restore side I believe and seems a lot more convoluted than what you're looking for. You could also look at [BCP out/in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802(v=sql.100).aspx).

Answer (score 4):

By making `.bak` file literally means taking a backup of the Database and Restoring it back. You don't have to do that here in your case.

`DTS` will solve it for you. Means you need to use the `Export Wizard`. Just follow the below steps.

Step 1: Right Click on the Database
Step 2: Select Task
Step 3: Select Export Data
Step 4: Enter Data Source details
Step 5: Enter Destination details
Step 6: Select the tables you want to recreate.

Thats it.